# Internal mouse location is above and left of physical mouse location

Tags: 16.04, mouse

For the past several weeks, I've been seeing odd behavior from my mouse on my Ubuntu VM (16.04).

For instance, if I want to resize a window by dragging the bottom right corner, if I put my mouse cursor right on the bottom right corner of the window, it doesn't render the "corner" icon that shows I can drag it.  However, if I move the mouse cursor perhaps 1/4 inch to the right and below, the icon does appear, and I can drag the window.

I've also noticed that some window widgets won't activate unless I move a similar distance below and to the right of the widget.

I've also tested this on VMs running Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10, and they do not have this problem.

**Update**:

Hmm, this may be a virtualbox problem.  I had the VM in "full-screen" mode.  I temporarily took it out of full-screen mode, and suddenly the location was ok.  I then put it BACK into full-screen mode, and the location was STILL fine.  Very weird.

**Update**:

I don't have a solution, but from [this forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=77605&p=362797#p362797) it's pretty clear it's not a fluke.  Several people have reported the same problem.

Comment: Might want to ask on Vbox forums. Have you installed guest additions? Are you running the latest version of Vbox?